# windows server samba share ping-able but not accessable

Tags: linux, windows, samba

me and my friend have made a closed network on vmware containing:

1. pfsense router with host-only card for LAN and a NAT card for WAN.
2. an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with samba installed and an existing share which is reachable via a normal install (before pfSense). a user + credentials have been added and enabled.
3. a bald windows server 2019 with "ONLY" ADDS installed. (domain and everything is working)

they can all ping eachother (linux>windows, windows>linux, both systems to pfsense router)

but the only thing i cannot do is add the samba server as a share to windows by typing in the address bar from windows explorer "\192.168.1.100". which in theory should present the windows credentials screen where i need to log in to. though it gives this error: [error windows server gives us](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbkYG.png)

but when i ping the samba server i get this:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ping 192.168.1.100

Pinging 192.168.1.100 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.100: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.100: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.100: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.100: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.100:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms
```

so we don't get why i cannot add it as a share nor access it via the search bar (also not visible in network, though in linux we can access it).

linux can also ping to windows so we are kinda lost, is there some option in pfSense we missed?

''all is done on one pc so we do not have to do any port forwarding to let machines outside this network access the machines, we only want the closed network to see the samba server so we can let the windows server do a backup to the smb server''

any help is welcome

Comment: Ping doesn't have anything to do with file sharing. The only thing ping tells you is that the server responds to ICMP echo requests.

Comment: The problem started when you changed the network configuration. So, this is where you have to investigate. I think pfsense can block ports; are the relevant ports open? You could run wireshark on the Windows host and tcpdump (or Wireshark) on the Ubuntu guest to see SMB packets. My guess is that those packets are not forwarded by the pfsense router. There must be diagnostic tools on pfsense as well.